# Reloading datatables issue with using Ajax.Reload();

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datatables

I'm currently trying to reload the datatable but it does not work half of the time. If I set a break point on it in the browser console it hits the line of code and refreshes the datable every time. I have no idea why this code breaks randomly sometimes after the fetch api call. I have been looking at this for a couple of hours and need another set of eyes. I have tried using a try catch block but it doesn't work 100% of the time either. I'm feeling like I'm using the event listener here completely wrong in this context.

```
const formAddUrl = document.getElementById('formAddUrl');

formAddUrl.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(this);

    let response = fetch('/LoanOfficerUrl/AddOfficerPararameter', {
        method: 'post',
        body: formData
    }); // It randomly breaks here in the code and doesn't make it to the next line of code.

    table.ajax.reload(); //If break point is set here it executes fine. If I don't it will randomly work.
});
```

```
//Load Datatable
var table = $('#OfficerTable').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: '/OfficerUrl/RetrieveOfficers',
        dataSrc: 'Officers'
    },
    columns: [
        { "data": "Id" },
        { "data": "FirstName" },
        { "data": "LastName" },
        { "data": "EmailAddress" },
        { "data": "OfficerUrlId" },
        { "data": "Url" },
        {
            "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                return '<a class="btn bg-green btn-sm"' + full[0] + '>' + 'Select' + '</a>';
            }
        }
    ],
    "order": [[0, 'asc']],
    rowGroup: {
        dataSrc: ["Id"],
        startRender: null,

        endRender: function (rows, group) {
            if (rows.count() > 1) {
                return $('<tr class="group group-start"><td class="'
                    + 'bg-green' + '" colspan="7">' + Officer Id: ' + group
                    + '&nbsp (' + 'Records: ' + rows.count() + ')' + '</td></tr>');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You can [edit] your question to show us your DataTable definition. Also, what does "does not work" mean? Are there any errors? If so, show us the full text (not screenshots) of the error message(s), in the question.

Comment: The `ajax.reload()` function is used to trigger the Ajax call _defined in your DataTable_. It appears from your question that you may have _two_ conflicting Ajax calls: (1) the one you show us which uses `fetch( ... )`, and the one (not shown) defined in your DataTable.

Comment: @andrewjames I have added the datatable definition.

Comment: I can see you have 2 conflicting calls, as suspected. You don't want that `fetch()` call since `table.ajax.reload()` will already cause the original Ajax call to be re-executed. If you want to use a different URL from the one defined in the DataTable, use [`table.ajax.url( ... ).load();`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url()) instead.

Comment: @andrewjames That fetch is used to a form update button. Does that change the issue because making that change didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Can you show what you tried, including how it relates to the updated button you mention? Show the most recent code attempt, explain how you want it to work, and describe what happened instead - with error messages: a [mre].

Comment: @andrewjames I have tried your suggested method and my previous method. I want the datatable to update and refresh when I use the update button. It semi works right now. It chooses when it updates. I have stepped through he code it it random will hit the table.Ajax.reload(); If I set a break on the table.Ajax.reload it hits that code and it works every time. I don't know exactly why yet.

Comment: Your comment does not provide the info I asked for - sorry, I cannot help you without that.

Comment: @andrewjames Well, thanks for your help.  I put a setTimeout(4000) and found out it is indeed refreshing the table but at the database has not yet updated yet so the new data cannot be retrieved yet. This is maybe the issue but have not fully tested it.

Comment: Glad you have a way forward! Be careful, though, that approach looks like a workaround rather than a solution.

Comment: Instead of using the setTimeout I used a alert() with a message to give time for the database to update. It's crazy how a couple of ms can change alot.